# How to print responseBody with java reactor webclient before deserialization

Tags: spring, project-reactor, spring-webclient

We are planing to migrate from spring Rest-Template to Reactor-webclient.

With Rest-template we have written custom logging interceptors where we were printing request and response with uniqueId, before desrialization.

Now weblient provide filters, but in filters I can't access responseBody to log it.

We have some third party APIs where they send strings in case of error and some objects in case of success. In this case I can't wait to log response after deserialization, because it will break and we will not be able to log what response we got.

Answer (score 4):

You can try creating a wrapper WebClient which will first log the response and then will deserialize.

The success response will fall on doOnSuccess and the error will fall on onErrorResume.

```
public <T> Mono<T> get(String url, Map<String, String> headersMap, Class<T> type) {

    Mono<T> responseMono = client.get().uri(url).headers((h) -> headersMap.forEach(h::set)).retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(type);

    return responseMono.doOnSuccess(response -> log.debug("REST GET call to {} is successfull and response is {}",
        url,response).onErrorResume(err -> {
          log.error("Exception occurred calling get({}): {}", url,
              err.getMessage());
          return Mono.error(err);
        });
  }
```

Comment: This only prints the body if there the deserialization is successful, also you're assuming that the model has an appropriate .toString() method.

Comment: The method is generic so use can pass String.class if you want to and it will work like your answer but if you are using your own model class then, of course, you know that the response will be of the type of expect model class.And if the deserialzation is not successfull then it will throw the deserialization error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sudo code for something I use to test with:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create("www.google.com");
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

client.get()
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(String.class)
    .map(rawBody -> {
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(rawBody, Response.class);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot deserialize string: " + rawBody);
        }
    });
```